# Android h264 decode non-existing PPS 0 referenced

Tags: android, ffmpeg, h.264, libx264

In Android JNI, using `ffmpeg with libx264` use below codes to encode and decode raw rgb data!. I should use swscale to convert rgb565 to yuv420p as required by H.264. But not clear about this conversion.Please help, where i am wrong, with regard the log i get!

## Code for Encoding

### codecinit()- called once(JNI wrapper function)

```
int Java_com_my_package_codecinit (JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
avcodec_register_all();
codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);//AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO);
if(codec->id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "set","h264_encoder");

if (!codec) {
    fprintf(stderr, "codec not found\n");
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "codec", "not found");

}
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "codec", "alloc-contest3");
c= avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
if(c == NULL)
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "avcodec","context-null");

picture= av_frame_alloc();

if(picture == NULL)
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "picture","context-null");

c->bit_rate = 400000;
c->height = 800;
c->time_base= (AVRational){1,25};
c->gop_size = 10; 
c->max_b_frames=1;
c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
outbuf_size = 768000;
c->width = 480;

size = (c->width * c->height);

if (avcodec_open2(c, codec,NULL) < 0) {

__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "codec", "could not open");


}

ret = av_image_alloc(picture->data, picture->linesize, c->width, c->height,
                     c->pix_fmt, 32);
if (ret < 0) {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "image","alloc-failed");
    fprintf(stderr, "could not alloc raw picture buffer\n");

}

picture->format = c->pix_fmt;
picture->width  = c->width;
picture->height = c->height;
return 0;

}
```

### encodeframe()-called in a while loop

```
int Java_com_my_package_encodeframe (JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,jbyteArray buffer) {
jbyte *temp= (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, buffer, 0);
Output = (char *)temp;
const uint8_t * const inData[1] = { Output }; 
const int inLinesize[1] = { 2*c->width };

//swscale should implement here

    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    pkt.data = NULL;    // packet data will be allocated by the encoder
    pkt.size = 0;

    fflush(stdout);
picture->data[0] = Output;
ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, picture,&got_output);

    fprintf(stderr,"ret = %d, got-out = %d \n",ret,got_output);
     if (ret < 0) {
                __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "error","encoding");
        if(got_output > 0)
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "got_output","is non-zero");

    }

    if (got_output) {
        fprintf(stderr,"encoding frame %3d (size=%5d): (ret=%d)\n", 1, pkt.size,ret);
        fprintf(stderr,"before caling decode");
        decode_inline(&pkt); //function that decodes right after the encode
        fprintf(stderr,"after caling decode");


        av_free_packet(&pkt);
    }


fprintf(stderr,"y val: %d \n",y);


(*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, buffer, Output, 0);
return ((ret));
}
```

### decode_inline() function

```
decode_inline(AVPacket *avpkt){
AVCodec *codec;
AVCodecContext *c = NULL;
int frame, got_picture, len = -1,temp=0;

AVFrame *rawFrame, *rgbFrame;
uint8_t inbuf[INBUF_SIZE + FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE];
char buf[1024];
char rawBuf[768000],rgbBuf[768000];

struct SwsContext *sws_ctx;

memset(inbuf + INBUF_SIZE, 0, FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);
avcodec_register_all();

c= avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
if(c == NULL)
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "avcodec","context-null");

codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
if (!codec) {
    fprintf(stderr, "codec not found\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "codec = %p \n", codec);
    }
c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
c->width = 480;
c->height = 800;

rawFrame = av_frame_alloc();
rgbFrame = av_frame_alloc();

if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "could not open codec\n");
    exit(1);
    }
sws_ctx = sws_getContext(c->width, c->height,/*PIX_FMT_RGB565BE*/
            PIX_FMT_YUV420P, c->width, c->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB565/*PIX_FMT_YUV420P*/,
            SWS_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);


frame = 0;

unsigned short *decodedpixels = &rawBuf;
rawFrame->data[0] = &rawBuf;
rgbFrame->data[0] = &rgbBuf;

fprintf(stderr,"size of avpkt %d \n",avpkt->size);
temp = avpkt->size;
while (temp > 0) {
        len = avcodec_decode_video2(c, rawFrame, &got_picture, avpkt);

        if (len < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while decoding frame %d\n", frame);
            exit(1);
            }
        temp -= len;
        avpkt->data += len;

        if (got_picture) {
            printf("saving frame %3d\n", frame);
            fflush(stdout);
        //TODO  
        //memcpy(decodedpixels,rawFrame->data[0],rawFrame->linesize[0]); 
        //  decodedpixels +=rawFrame->linesize[0];

            frame++;
            }

        }

avcodec_close(c);
av_free(c);
//free(rawBuf);
//free(rgbBuf);
av_frame_free(&rawFrame);
av_frame_free(&rgbFrame);
```

}

### The log i get

For the decode_inline() function:

---

```
01-02 14:50:50.160: I/stderr(3407): [h264 @ 0x8db540] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
01-02 14:50:50.160: I/stderr(3407): [h264 @ 0x8db540] decode_slice_header error
01-02 14:50:50.160: I/stderr(3407): [h264 @ 0x8db540] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
01-02 14:50:50.160: I/stderr(3407): [h264 @ 0x8db540] decode_slice_header error
01-02 14:50:50.160: I/stderr(3407): [h264 @ 0x8db540] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
01-02 14:50:50.160: I/stderr(3407): [h264 @ 0x8db540] decode_slice_header error
01-02 14:50:50.160: I/stderr(3407): [h264 @ 0x8db540] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
01-02 14:50:50.160: I/stderr(3407): [h264 @ 0x8db540] decode_slice_header error
01-02 14:50:50.160: I/stderr(3407): [h264 @ 0x8db540] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
01-02 14:50:50.160: I/stderr(3407): [h264 @ 0x8db540] decode_slice_header error
01-02 14:50:50.160: I/stderr(3407): [h264 @ 0x8db540] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
01-02 14:50:50.160: I/stderr(3407): [h264 @ 0x8db540] decode_slice_header error
01-02 14:50:50.160: I/stderr(3407): [h264 @ 0x8db540] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
01-02 14:50:50.160: I/stderr(3407): [h264 @ 0x8db540] decode_slice_header error
01-02 14:50:50.160: I/stderr(3407): [h264 @ 0x8db540] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
01-02 14:50:50.160: I/stderr(3407): [h264 @ 0x8db540] decode_slice_header error
01-02 14:50:50.160: I/stderr(3407): [h264 @ 0x8db540] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
01-02 14:50:50.160: I/stderr(3407): [h264 @ 0x8db540] decode_slice_header error
01-02 14:50:50.160: I/stderr(3407): [h264 @ 0x8db540] Invalid mix of idr and non-idr slices
01-02 14:50:50.160: I/stderr(3407): Error while decoding frame 0
```

### Edit: Changing GOP value:

If i change `c->gop_size = 3;` as expected it emits `one I frame` every three frames. The `non-existing PPS 0 referenced` message is not there for in every third execution, but all other have this message

Comment: Managed to work it,, but decoded picture is too bad, its in resolution of 1/1000 of source!! So bad, need to know right parameters, Please help any codec genies!!

Answer (score 1):

In your decode_inline() method, right after specifying the size, here are some codec parameters that you can play with to get the higher quality. I filled in the values to get you started:

```
c->gop_size = 10;                                       // one intra frame every ten frames
c->max_b_frames = 1;                                    // max # of b-frames 
c->keyint_min = 1;                                      // min GOP size
c->i_quant_factor = (float)0.71;                        // qscale factor between P and I frames
c->b_frame_strategy = 20;                               
c->refs = 4;                                            // number of reference frames
c->trellis = 1;                                         // trellis RD Quantization
c->qcompress = (float)0.8;                              
c->qmin = 20;                                           // min quantizer
c->qmax = 51;                                           // max quantizer
c->max_qdiff = 4;                                       // max quantizer difference between frames
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: So you mean we should use the same parameters explicitly as was in encode stage? Doesn't it in `SPS & PPS` ?

Comment: Essentially I am trying to get your encoder and decoder on the same page. Do you still see the same error after making the changes from above? Also, are you sure your RGB data is in AV_PIX_FMT_RGB565 format? I have done some encoding/decoding on android, and I only had PIX_FMT_RGBA format option. But again that was from actual devices, I am not sure if you getting raw frames from somewhere else...

Comment: i am getting raw frames from user images, converting them to RGB565. So these images are generated(assume). I still see that after using it..:(

Comment: See if playing with some of the codec parameters above will get you higher quality. I prefilled them to get you started. You only need to specify this in the encode step.

Comment: Thanks Aki, i will check around

Comment: It seems setup is ok!! But, the decoded frame resolution goes on degraded as time moves. i.e.,the first frame is somewhat good looking, further frames keep on decreased in quality, and after a minute or more i see black boxes coming up!! the image becomes too much degraded

Answer (score 0):

the same problem
use rtsp H264,ffmpeg
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).